# How do I update text on splash screen?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm pretty new to tkinter and have been experimenting with some sample codes to get a better understanding of it. I'm trying to create a splash screen that does some initialization of the program I intent to run. Since the initialization may take a while depending on network connections, I'm trying to get the splash screen to provide status as the app is being initialized.. all my searches has led to StringVar as a solution but I'm lost as to why this method isn't working for me. I'd love some help on this and getting a better understanding on what to do.

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time, sleep, clock
class Splash:

    def __init__(self, root, file, wait):
        self.__root = root
        self.__file = file
        self.__wait = wait + clock()


    def __enter__(self):
        # Hide the root while it is built.
        self.__root.withdraw()
        # Create components of splash screen.
        window = Toplevel(self.__root)
        splash = PhotoImage(master=window, file=self.__file)
        canvas = Label(window, text=d_status.get(), fg='white', bg='black', image=splash, compound=TOP)
        # Get the screen's width and height.
        scrW = window.winfo_screenwidth()
        scrH = window.winfo_screenheight()
        # Get the images's width and height.
        imgW = splash.width()
        imgH = splash.height()
        # Compute positioning for splash screen.
        Xpos = (scrW - imgW) // 2
        Ypos = (scrH - imgH) // 2
        # Configure the window showing the logo.
        window.overrideredirect(True)
        window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(Xpos, Ypos))
        canvas.grid()
        # Show the splash screen on the monitor.
        window.update()
        # Save the variables for later cleanup.
        self.__window = window
        self.__canvas = canvas
        self.__splash = splash

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Ensure that required time has passed.
        now = clock()
        if now < self.__wait:
            sleep(self.__wait - now)
        # Free used resources in reverse order.
        del self.__splash
        self.__canvas.destroy()
        self.__window.destroy()
        # Give control back to the root program.
        self.__root.update_idletasks()
        self.__root.deiconify()

def initializeMyApplication():
    for x in range(5):
        d_status.set(x)
        sleep(1)
        print(d_status.get())

def buildTheGUI(object):
    for x in range(100, 110):
        sleep(1)
        print(x)

root = Tk()
d_status = StringVar()
d_status.set("Initializing...")
with Splash(root, 'pix.gif', 3.0):
   initializeMyApplication()
   d_status.set("Done!")
   buildTheGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```